# How to add a Flow button to a Lightning Highlights Panel?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, visual-workflow, quickaction

We have created a flow and a Flow action button. We'd like to add the button to the Lightning Highlights Panel on a case detail page. However, despite adding the button to the page layout in the Salesforce1 / Lightning Experience section, the button does not show.

The user viewing the case details page in LEX is an Admin.

What do we need to do in order to get our flow button to show on a Lightning Highlights Panel?

Comment: you've checked to make sure the user/ users profile has access to the flow?

Comment: Is this on case object? Can you tell which object is it?

Answer (score 3):

**Actions on user profiles, cases, and work orders can appear in a different way than on other records.**

Actions on the user profile page come from the Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher section of the global publisher layout. Only standard Chatter actions appear on the user profile page, regardless of which actions are assigned to the User Page Layout or the global publisher layout.

When **feed tracking is enabled** for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons. Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

> So to make it work in highlights panel you need to disable the feed
>   tracking

[Actions in lighting experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5)