# Lightning Flow from a Case

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, quickaction

I've created a simple Lightning Flow that shows just one screen.  That screen includes a Lightning component with one input field.  (This is a very simple test case.) Then, from the Case object, I created an Action that calls the Flow.  I then added the action to the standard Case page layout.  When I open an existing Case record, I don't see the button I added to the page layout.  I see that there may have been a change with Winter '18 that restricts Actions to specific Record Types.  I don't understand what the following linked references are telling me.  Is there a way I associate an Action with a Record Type?

[Quick Actions and Record Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_and_record_types.htm&type=5)

[Custom Quick Action is not visible for affected profiles in the Page Layout in Lightning Experience in Winter '18](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCYiQAM&title=custom-quick-action-is-not-visible-for-affected-profiles-in-the-page-layout-in-lightning-experience-in-winter-18)

It looks like there was a similar post on this issue a year ago, with no definitive answer:

[Actions on Case object in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157345/actions-on-case-object-in-lightning)

Answer (score 0):

> **Short Answer:** To get your button on case highlights panel you need to
>   **disable the feed tracking**.

**Long Answer:** Actions on user profiles, cases, and work orders can appear in a different way than on other records.

Actions on the user profile page come from the Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher section of the global publisher layout. Only standard Chatter actions appear on the user profile page, regardless of which actions are assigned to the User Page Layout or the global publisher layout.

When feed tracking is enabled for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons. Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

**Record Types:** You need to assign actions independently on each recordtype you need the action.

**Reference:**

- [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5)
- [How to add a Flow button to a Lightning Highlights Panel?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236906/how-to-add-a-flow-button-to-a-lightning-highlights-panel)